# Django - mysite.wsgi - file is not present but uWSGI works. How?

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

There is some magic around how uWSGI works (I'm using it with Django) which I just don't understand.

I have the following test Django project:

```
(uwsgi-tutorial)[root@localhost mysite]# tree
.
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|-- mysite
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __pycache__
|   |   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
|   |   |-- settings.cpython-34.pyc
|   |   |-- urls.cpython-34.pyc
|   |   `-- wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
`-- test.py
```

In this folder I run `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi`
And it works.

How?

I mean, there is no such file as **mysite.wsgi**. However there is **mysite/wsgi.py**. Now if I run `uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite/wsgi.py`, it doesn't work (HTTP 500).

If I change **mysite.wsgi** to anything else then uWSGI is unable to load the module, so it looks like module name must match Django project name and you have to add **.wsgi** to enable the "magic".

Most uWSGI+Django guides, including the official [Django 1.8 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/%20%22Django%201.8%20documentation)
say something like:

*module: The WSGI module to use – **probably** the **mysite.wsgi** module that **startproject** creates*

or

*module **mysite.wsgi**: load the specified wsgi module*

I do not understand how it works and why it works this way. Can anyone explain? :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

After playing around a bit I seem to have understood what's really happening - **module** is a **Python module reference**, like for an **import** statement in Python.

I thought that uWSGI is a universal thing and not tied to Python, so why would it expect a Python module reference? Looks like uWSGI was initially developed for Python. The rest of the options are available via --plugins and custom builds. So when I installed uWSGI via **pip install uwsgi** is was compiled with default settings, which means it expects a Python module reference. At least this is how I understand it now.

So I can, for example, rename **wsgi.py** inside **mysite/** folder into **socool.py** and run my setup via `uswgi --http :8000 --module mysite.socool`.

If anyone can add clarity to my reply that would be great.

**UPDATE-01:**

At least with Arch Linux distribution there is a difference between **uwsgi** system package installed via **pacman -S uwsgi** and the Python package installed with **pip install uwsgi**.

If a system package is installed, it will not have Python capabilities out of the box. For example, running `uwsgi --module ...` will give an error that **module** option is not supported.

Using uWSGI system package to run Python module is possible only after installing **uwsgi-plugin-python**. Also it is necessary to specify the plugin to be used - `uwsgi --plugins python ...`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# uwsgi --help | grep module | wc -l
0
[root@localhost ~]# uwsgi --plugins python --help | grep module | wc -l
23
```

Suddenly it turns out that extra options appear in help output, and **--module** is now supported.

Hope this helps those who are unfamiliar with uWSGI like myself.

Comment: WSGI is a Python standard. uWSGI is an implementation of that standard that has subsequently been extended to other languages.